# Permission issue accessing /dev/mem – gpio node-rpio

Tags: gpio, rpio

I am somewhat of a newbie, so please let me know if there is a way I can go about this better.

I'm working on doing some LED coding (WS8201 strip) with node.js and it appears I am having trouble accessing /dev/mem. I have spent hours on this and tried pretty much every I can find regarding permission issues. ([here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root), [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47020/accessing-gpio-not-working-as-non-root-cant-open-dev-mem-permission-denie), [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/permissions-on-dev-entries), and many other places)

My issue is regarding [this tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio). During the install section I am receiving the following error regarding permission.

```
cat >/etc/udev/rules.d/20-gpiomem.rules <<EOF
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
EOF
-bash: /etc/udev/rules.d/20-gpiomem.rules: Permission denied`
```

I went ahead and tried running some test code anyways and received the following error.

```
bcm2835_init: Unable to open /dev/mem: Permission denied
/home/pi/node_modules/rpio/lib/rpio.js:104
return bindfunc(optarg);
       ^
Error: Could not initialize bcm2835 GPIO library`
```

I am unsure if these errors are directly related or what to do from here since I've tinkered with permission settings for hours and nothing seems to work. I appreciate the help and please let me know if there is additional information needed!

Thank you

Comment: I can't help with java BUT `/dev/mem` requires root permission - for compiled c code this can be managed but python requires programs to be run with `sudo`. [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/sitemap.html) has access, but I do not know if helps with java. `/dev/gpiomem` provides access to members of group `gpio`